# Prevent Xcode from keeping an old version of a project folder that I want to rename

Tags: xcode, filenames, project-organization

I'm using Xcode Version 6.4 (6E35b)on a mid 2013 MacBook Air running OS X 10.10.5.

A few days ago, with my code in something of a tangle, Xcode crashed. After the crash, my app built and ran, but didn't do anything except eat memory at a fantastically fast rate.

I keep a git repository and every now and then a put a copy of the whole project folder on an offsite location.

I got one of my older versions out of storage, did a build and run and the same thing happened.

All copies of the same project (by name) now do the same thing. Run, eat memory, and nothing else.

I tried removing DerivedData, removing contents of /var/folders/, removing and replacing schema (in schema -> manage), removing all projects, emptying trash,  and have removed Xcode (using "trash me") and reinstalling. No joy. Still the same thing.

I was wanting to change the name of the project anyhow, so I changed the name, and it works. Unfortunately, I can't seem to change the name of the folder containing the project. Using the file inspector, I'm able to change the names of almost everything, but info.plist wants to keep an extra copy of the old project folder name in it's path, as far as DerivedData and LLVM are concerned.

Right now I will continue working with the old project folder name, but new project name.

How do I make Xcode forget the old folder name?

Comment: "Where Xcode keeps everything" seems to be too broad -- even [a list question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124450/what-is-the-definition-of-a-list-question). Does my edit reflect the specific information you're actually after?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I'm not sure if it covers "everything". From other similar questions I've gotten the list of things to delete I listed above.

Comment: There is something going on beyond DerivedData, /var/folders, the many files that "trash me" removes, and whatever the path changes you can make using file inspector.

Comment: To get the right path for info.plist I had to change it in BuildSettings, not just in the file inspector panel. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159090/how-to-tell-xcode-where-my-info-plist-and-pch-files-are

Comment: I don't have a complete answer, but finally I was able to muddle through changing both the project name and path. I still haven't been able to fix the original project by its original name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As edited by John Caswell, the answer is basically covered by a careful reading of [Duplicate and rename Xcode project & associated folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744319/duplicate-and-rename-xcode-project-associated-folders). I'm going to close this and resubmit the parts of the question that aren't answered.