# React Native ios build failed on react-native run-ios

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, terminal

getting this error

> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
>   CompileC /Users/karthikn/AwesomeProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTTabBarItem.o Views/RCTTabBarItem.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>   (1 failure)
>
> Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AwesomeProject.app
>   An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
>   Failed to install the requested application
>   An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
>   Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
>   Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
>
> Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AwesomeProject.app/Info.plist
>   Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Answer (score 7):

Xcode 8.2 still occur same error. Three lines bellow fixed it for me :)
Downgrade react(16.0.0-alpha.12 -> 16.0.0-alpha.6) & react-native(0.45.0 -> 0.44.0)
**rm -rf node_modules/react** 
**npm i react@16.0.0-alpha.6** -S
**npm i react-native@0.44.0** -S
Then run **react-native run-ios**

Comment: Thanks a lot. Save my afternoon.

Answer (score 4):

Your build could be failing because of the current node js version installed, or due to your pod files or a number of other reasons.

This error may also be when cloning a react native repository from github.

This solution may work as I was able to recreate this issue(refer to the screen shots):

**Solution one:**

firstly:

If you have the latest version of node js installed you may have some compatibility issues with some of the dependencies, install the recommended version of Nodejs instead.

[image]

after installation, reinstall your dependencies and update your pod files:

```
npm install
cd ios
pod install
```

or

```
pod update
```

**solution two:**

this can happen if you haven't installed react native previously on your system and are trying to run a clone react native repository from github.

```
brew install watchman
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

then in the rn project clone

```
 cd ios 
 pod install
```

**Problem:**

*This is what the error message looks like:*

**legacy compatibility issues:**

[image]

**Build failed**

[image]

**Solution:**

*After following the above steps this issue was resolved instantly:*

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If it's your first project, you may have the same problem than me:
do NOT use space in your project path!

Comment: Hi, I have since then used expo to initialize my react native projects

Comment: I believe the build was failing because I was using an outdated version of xCode

Comment: This works for me I had a 2 spaces in my project name replace it with dash. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

1. If your xcode is open, close it
2. Remove DrivedData
3. Update your pod files using `pod update` command
4. Run `npx react-native ios` command

its worked for me i hope work for you too

Comment: Worked for me. My original error was with Flipper-Folly, broke in DistributedMutex.cpp after an XCode update. `pod update` updated Flipper-Folly and resolved the build error.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good chance you're running an outdated version of React-Native and your template is no longer compatible.

There are [instructions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html) provided on ways to upgrade.

The simplest would be to run `react-native upgrade` and you'll be prompted with files react-native wants to overwrite.  Clicking yes through all the prompts solved this issue for me but if you're concerned about losing any changes, it's recommended to install `npm install -g react-native-git-upgrade` and merge any conflicts after running `react-native-git-upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

Check this In Your info.plist Bundle identifier

Or Add this Bundle identifier name as --> com.cmpname.yourapp // change name according

[image]

Comment: where's this Your info? I'm new to xcode and react native.

Comment: In xcode  project left menu search  info.plist or you can follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159090/how-to-tell-xcode-where-my-info-plist-and-pch-files-are

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT use space in project path. It had solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace Boost C++ Libraries  with this one [Download Link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.63.0/)

> /node_modules/react-native/third-party/boost_1_63_0

Answer (score 0):

Try sudo react-native run-ios
This helped me

Comment: Oddly enough running this results in the app not launching at all

Comment: when u do sudo react-native run-ios this command wil start your packager but not the simulator, so if you do react-native run-ios in the same terminal after the previous command finishes it will launch the simulator

You should have the jsBundle file in your project otherwise it will throw error again

Answer (score -2):

seems like there is an issue with the react-native version, downgrading the version will resolve the issue. Use the following commands:

- rm -rf node_modules/react
- npm i react@16.0.0-alpha.6 -S
- npm i react-native@0.44.0-alpha.6 -S
- react-native run-ios

Answer (score -3):

There are different problems that cause this issue. I'll post here what I did to resolve in my case.

1 - Delete the folder node_modules and the folders of android and ios from project root:

```
rm -rf node_modules/ ios/ android/
```

2 - Rebuild the folders:

```
npm install && react-native upgrade
```

or (If you have used yarn in the project)

```
yarn install && react-native upgrade
```

3 - After that, just run the command again:

```
react-native run-ios
```

or

```
react-native run-android.
```

I hope it helped =)

Comment: deleting ios and android folder in a production app is not good practice