# failing to build ios project react native

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm encountering an issue while trying to build my React Native iOS app using the command npx react-native run-ios. The build fails with the following error message:

```
error Failed to build iOS project. "xcodebuild" exited with error code '65'. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening 'AwesomeProject.xcodeproj'.
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project AwesomeProject.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -scheme AwesomeProject -destination id=0433ACB5-66D6-43A0-B3A4-9D2FCEDD8295

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Prepare packages

ComputeTargetDependencyGraph
note: Building targets in dependency order
note: Target dependency graph (1 target)
    Target 'AwesomeProject' in project 'AwesomeProject' (no dependencies)

GatherProvisioningInputs

CreateBuildDescription
Build description signature: fdee7c632ff6d82e4834c3c1af996810
Build description path: /Users/user249711/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject-ddidwfsiihymrzdbvusyfsonvmyt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/fdee7c632ff6d82e4834c3c1af996810.xcbuilddata

/Users/user249711/Projects/AwesomeProject/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-AwesomeProject/Pods-AwesomeProject.debug.xcconfig:1:1: error: unable to open configuration settings file
warning: Unable to read contents of XCFileList '/Target Support Files/Pods-AwesomeProject/Pods-AwesomeProject-frameworks-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'AwesomeProject' from project 'AwesomeProject')
warning: Unable to read contents of XCFileList '/Target Support Files/Pods-AwesomeProject/Pods-AwesomeProject-resources-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'AwesomeProject' from project 'AwesomeProject')
error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-AwesomeProject/Pods-AwesomeProject-frameworks-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'AwesomeProject' from project 'AwesomeProject')
error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-AwesomeProject/Pods-AwesomeProject-frameworks-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'AwesomeProject' from project 'AwesomeProject')
error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-AwesomeProject/Pods-AwesomeProject-resources-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'AwesomeProject' from project 'AwesomeProject')
warning: Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'AwesomeProject' from project 'AwesomeProject')
error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-AwesomeProject/Pods-AwesomeProject-resources-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'AwesomeProject' from project 'AwesomeProject')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'AwesomeProject' from project 'AwesomeProject')
warning: Run script build phase '[CP] Copy Pods Resources' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'AwesomeProject' from project 'AwesomeProject')

--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:0433ACB5-66D6-43A0-B3A4-9D2FCEDD8295, OS:17.2, name:iPhone 11 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:0433ACB5-66D6-43A0-B3A4-9D2FCEDD8295, OS:17.2, name:iPhone 11 }
** BUILD FAILED **
```

I've tried a few things like cleaning the build, updating pods, and ensuring that the Xcode project file is correctly configured, but the issue persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the answer to your question, click this link.

1. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33793
2. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24450
3. [React Native ios build failed on react-native run-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43391417/react-native-ios-build-failed-on-react-native-run-ios)
4. If you don't have cocoa pods installed you need to

   sudo gem install cocoapods

   run cd ios

   run pod install

   cd ..

   delete build folder

   run react-native run-ios

if the error persists,

delete build folder again

open the /ios folder in x-code

navigate File -> Project Settings -> Build System -> change (Shared workspace settings and Per-User workspace settings): Build System -> Legacy Build System`

You can easily achieve what you want using this approach.